# Does RxJava PublishProcessor cares about back pressure by default?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-java3

I wanna know more about RxJava PublishProcessor. Does it handle back pressure by default or we should add this behavior to it by onBackPressure funtions?

Comment: "I wanna know more about RxJava PublishProcessor" - http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/3.0.0/io/reactivex/rxjava3/processors/PublishProcessor.html

Answer (score 0):

By this [link](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/processors/PublishProcessor.html) I realized that it doesn't handle backpressure by default.
If you want to add back pressure behavior to it, you can use `onBackpressureBuffer` that is overloaded with different inputs.